# Merging URL encoding and HTML encoding tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

**The following tags exist that represent HTML encoding:**

[html-encode](/questions/tagged/html-encode) **× 112**
[htmlencode](/questions/tagged/htmlencode) **× 58**
[html-encoding](/questions/tagged/html-encoding) **× 10**

---

**The following tags exist that represent URL encoding:**

[urlencode](/questions/tagged/urlencode) **× 526**
[url-encoding](/questions/tagged/url-encoding) **× 237**

---

**The following tags exist that represent HTML entities:**

[html-entities](/questions/tagged/html-entities) **× 227**
[htmlentities](/questions/tagged/htmlentities) **× 98**
[html-entity-decode](/questions/tagged/html-entity-decode) **× 25** - It's a specific PHP function but is closely enough related.
[html-entity](/questions/tagged/html-entity) **× 3**
[htmlentitydefs](/questions/tagged/htmlentitydefs) **× 3** - What exactly is this?

---

Comment: URL encoding and HTML entities are distinct topics; what is "HTML encoding?" There is the text encoding of the HTML document, and also there is converting plain text to HTML. Which of these, or both, are your first group of tags used for? If both, they should be separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally gotten around to this. All of the [html-entities](/questions/tagged/html-entities) stuff was already taken care of by someone else. The [url-encoding](/questions/tagged/url-encoding) and [urldecode](/questions/tagged/urldecode) tags should be merged into [urlencode](/questions/tagged/urlencode) by a moderator (that's a lot of stuff, and I've already flooded enough with the ones I did).

All of the following tags were merged into [html-encode](/questions/tagged/html-encode):

- [html-encoding](/questions/tagged/html-encoding)
- [htmlencode](/questions/tagged/htmlencode)
- [htmldecode](/questions/tagged/htmldecode)
- [html-decode](/questions/tagged/html-decode)
- [html-entity-decode](/questions/tagged/html-entity-decode)

If a moderator could set up a synonym `html-encode <-- html-decode` that would be great.

Although [htmlspecialchars](/questions/tagged/htmlspecialchars) is an actual function in PHP, it should still be merged and synonymized into [html-encode](/questions/tagged/html-encode) as it *is* encoding HTML entities, it's just a slightly different way of doing it in PHP. There's nothing particularly "special" about it that it needs its own tag.

Comment: Following some kind of convention, I guess it would be better to define an `url-encode` tag, because it separates the words with a score, like `html-entities` and `html-encode`. However, it will be a lot of work to do, and I guess that at SO is preferable to use an existing tag, rather than defining a new one just for the sake of "convention".

Answer (score 5):

Both [url-encoding](/questions/tagged/url-encoding) (244) and [urlencode](/questions/tagged/urlencode) (551) are widely used, but still require merge!