# are urlencode and url-encoding tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Merging URL encoding and HTML encoding tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122590/merging-url-encoding-and-html-encoding-tags)

#### update

Formal suggestion for making tag synonyms has been created:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaIlt.jpg]

<sub>Note for the reasoning in favor of above suggestion, refer to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129246/165773)</sub>

---

As of now, [urlencode](/questions/tagged/urlencode) has 501 questions, [url-encoding](/questions/tagged/url-encoding) has 223, and 31 questions are [tagged with both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/+urlencode+url-encoding).

Are these tags synonyms?

Tag wiki excerpt for *urlencode* says

> about encoding text in/for a url. Some characters are not valid for URLs...

Tag wiki for *url-encoding* are empty. If these tags are not synonyms, it would be nice to have it filled.

---

For the record, comparing top users in these tags shows pretty little intersection - 3 users <sub>(and 1 super-user whose presence in top of any tag only proves that tag makes sense, nothing else)</sub>

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvXIh.jpg]

Comment: `urlencode` is a specific function in some languages (PHP, possibly others), while url-encoding is the generic topic. (This is not a reason not to merge them, but just a thought.)

Comment: Is bobince the "super-user" of which you speak?

Comment: @TheEstablishment but of course, who else could that be! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick glance over the current questions in both tags indicates that the questions are really all over the place; many different languages, many libraries, very little in common. There's no reason for a fully filled out tag wiki (particularly of [urlencode](/questions/tagged/urlencode)) and there's no reason for someone to subscribe (they'll be very unlikely to be able to answer most of the questions being asked). They could all be sensibly done under one tag with the other being a synonym — the generic term — and nothing of value would be lost.

Comment: your reasoning in favor of making these synonyms sounds compelling. Someone created a [formal suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/urlencode/synonyms) at SO and someone else voted it up (I plan to update the question with that)